# Sass not detecting changes made by used files @use

Tags: sass, phpstorm

Alright so I am trying to detect changes that happened in the files that are used (@use) with SASS and PHPSTORM but whenever I compile the used file, it doesnt compile the original.

Example:

I save _global.sass, it doesnt compile style.sass, but it should.

So basically my issue is that whenever I make changes to _global.sass or _home.sass, I have to manually go to style.sass, insert or delete empty line (make some changes) and then save for it to compile...

style.sass

```
@use "_global.sass"
@use "_home.sass"
```

_global.sass

```
*
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.flex
    display: flex
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-42904](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42904) for updates; problem is caused by limited support for SASS `@use`/`@forward` directives ([WEB-42184](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42184))