# WebStorm doesn't compile main SCSS on partial update

Tags: sass, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm building in WebStorm.
I have a **main.scss** witch references several partial files (names prefixed with **_**) via `@use`. I have a file watcher set up and everything works fine when I'm working in the **main.scss** - I make changes, they get compiled and are reflected in my build.

When I make change in a partial though they don't seem to trigger the file watcher. In order for the changes to show in the build I have to jump back to **main.scss** and make some small change that triggers the watcher and everything gets compiled. This is a bit of a pain to keep having to do but I've tried messing around with the watcher settings and have had no luck.

Can anyone suggest a way to trigger the file watcher when partial SCSS files are updated?

Thanks

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577807/783119

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer as WebStorm just doesn't seem to want to play ball but in the end I set up `webpack` and am using the [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) which seems to work as desired and actually makes more sense as I'll usually be running `webpack` anyway.